# Android bitmap OOM ( out of memory error )

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, crash, listadapter

Im new at using Java and Android Dev anyway my android application crashes when i use it for 5 min , and it shows the OOM error on Logs .
my App shows a list of Item On a ListView , Every Item Contains a Bitmap And Informations Both are Requested From Database , Here is The Code Of My Activity class :

```
public class QuotesActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<Quote> imageArry = new ArrayList<Quote>();
private QuotesListAdapter adapter;
private String Activitytype;
private DataBaseHandler db;
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    Activitytype = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mode");

    }

    if (Activitytype.equals("allQuotes")) {

        List<Quote> contacts = db.getAllQuotes();
        for (Quote cn : contacts) {

            imageArry.add(cn);

        }
        ;

        }

    adapter = new QuotesListAdapter(this, R.layout.quote_items, imageArry);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

    dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long idInDB) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    QuoteActivity.class);
            Quote srr = imageArry.get(position);
            i.putExtra("id", srr.getID());
            i.putExtra("mode", "");

            startActivity(i);

        }

    });

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layAdsQuotes);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quotes, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.finish();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Im using A List Adapter for my ListView , and Here is the Class ListAdapter .

```
public class QuotesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Quote> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
private int lastPosition = -1;

ArrayList<Quote> data = new ArrayList<Quote>();

public QuotesListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Quote> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    ImageHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.rgb(26, 188, 156));
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtQuote = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtQuote);
        holder.txtCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(font);
        holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(16);
        holder.txtQuote.setTypeface(font);
        holder.txtQuote.setTextSize(16);
        holder.txtCategory.setTypeface(font);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    row.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    Quote picture = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(picture.getName());
    holder.txtQuote.setText(picture.getQuote());

    holder.txtCategory.setText("    " + picture.getCategory() + "    ");

    byte[] outImage = picture.getImage();
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    return row;
}

static class ImageHolder {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtQuote;
    TextView txtCategory;

}
```

}

Please consider tht this view doesnt crash at the first time , it doesnt crashe until i enter many time to that activy , thank you .

Comment: if you are loading all your bitmap images into a List which it appears so by your code then yes you will get OOM errors. you should keep a reference to the image like the file path or something and only load them in the list when you need it

Comment: How many contacts do you have and exactly how large are the images you are loading for each contact?

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak since you aren't disposing of your bitmaps when your activity finishes. You need to call the recycle method on your bitmaps in order to free up the memory used by them when you no longer need them. Or to optimize further, look into caching your bitmaps [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) in order to keep those images in memory if you are hitting that activity a lot with the same images.

Comment: you should probably determine WHERE in your code you're getting the OOM.  Is in your adapter when reading the image stream? Is it in the ImgArry.add()?

Comment: This is incorrect, if a bitmap is only referenced by the Activity its memory will be reclaimed automatically. recycle() is useful only to pre-Honeycomb devices to provide predictable memory reclamation purpose.